# Changing date/time settings of mobile phone through programmatically in Android,Blackberry?

Tags: java, android, iphone, blackberry, mobile-application

How should change the date/time settings of the Android mobile phone through Android programming.

It is possible or not.In J2me it is not possible to change the mobile phone's date/time settings.

I want to know it is possible in Android?

I want to know it is possible in blackberry,iphone,etc through mobile application?

Comment: not allowed in android `SET_TIME` is system permission.

Comment: changing the date and time is a distinct question for each platform.  Since you're asking about android, blackberry, and iphone, this is actually three distinct questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in j2me,blackberry.But it is possible in android.